# Check leap year in C#

Tags: c#

I want to add entry date + 1year to a column called finishing date.

If the entry date is in leap yr, i need to add 364 days, if not 365 days.

Is there a way to check this in c#, using current datetime's year & manipulate leap yr/not, then add the days.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just use `DateTime.AddYears(1)`?

Comment: You should add 366 days if it is a leap year :)

Comment: Or 365, if the date is past Feb 29. But .AddYears(1) is the more carefree version.

Comment: 5/6ths of the leap year concern would actually be the year before leap year, would it not? Using the day methodology, you would need to modify the days added starting at March 1 of the previous year going through Feb 29 of the leap year. In related news, when I take over the world, the calendar will be completely refactored, making the *present* leap day moot.

Comment: @ Job B - Excellent idea, DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) is what i have added in the code.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime.IsLeapYear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.isleapyear.aspx) method.

But just for handling that you do not really need to use that method. `DateTime.AddYears` takes leap years into account.

```
var leapYear = new DateTime(2000, 2, 29);
Console.WriteLine("Is 2000 a leap year? {0}", DateTime.IsLeapYear(leapYear.Year)); // 2000 is a leap year
Console.WriteLine("One year added to {0} is {1}", leapYear, leapYear.AddYears(1)); // 2000-02-29 plus 1 year is 2001-02-28
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am using DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) in the code which is 1 line of code & more logical.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 - Of course, `AddYears` is better than `IsLeapYear` in your situation. I have also included that in the answer. Though a minute after Jon B's comment, true :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateStart = new DateTime(2010,1,10);  // Some date to check
var newDate = DateTime.IsLeapYear(dateStart.Year) ? dateStart.AddDays(365) : dateStart.AddDays(364);
// or 
var newDate = dateStart.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this neater as an extension method:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLeapYear(this DateTime source)
    {
        return DateTime.IsLeapYear(source.Year);
    }
}
```