# Check to see if year is leap year

Tags: c#, datetime

```
<script Language="c#" runat="server">
  void Page_Load()
  {
   int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year();

   if (currentYear % 400 == 0) {
     Message2.Text = ("This is a leap year");
   }
   else {
     Message2.Text = ("This is not a leap year");
   }

 }
```

Currently I am getting a RunTime error. My goal is to test whether or not the current year, using DateTime.Now.Year()  is a leap year or not. I think the issue is that I am not properly converting year to int? Please advise.

Comment: [`Year`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.year.aspx) is a property rather than a method. So, no need for calling parenthesis – `int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;`

Comment: Oh wow, that was silly of me... Thank you!

Comment: Why are you doing it by 400? 2016 is a leap year, but 2016/400 = 5.04

Comment: @Greg Excellent point! I hadn't quite gotten to the logic due to the error, but I've got it now!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check leap year in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128391/check-leap-year-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @KeithNicholas I am not looking to use the DateTime.IsLeapYear.

Comment: you accepted an answer which exactly used that

Answer (score 30):

You can just use [DateTime.IsLeapYear()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.isleapyear(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(year)) 
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Available since .net Framework so since question is six years old, it would be guaranteed available. DateTime.IsLeapYear is not new in .net. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.isleapyear?view=netframework-1.1

Answer (score 5):

For those that come here for the rules:

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year), these extra days occur in each year

- which is an integer multiple of 4.
- years that are evenly divisible by 100 are not leap years unless evenly divisible by 400.

So this results in this function:

```
// PRE: no year < 1 or > 9999
// POST: true if year is a leap year, or false if not.
public static bool IsLeapYear(int year) 
{
    if (year < 1 || year > 9999) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("year", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Year"));
    }
    return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
}
```

And now I'm wondering what should happen if I use minus-years for BC - actually, the question is which calendar does even apply, especially prior to 1753 (for Britain) ?  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use C# and this code for leap years.
cheers

```cs
if ((jahr % 4 == 0 && jahr % 400 == 0) || (jahr % 4 == 0 && !(jahr % 100 == 0)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(jahr + " ist ein Schaltjahr");
}
else
    Console.WriteLine(jahr + " ist kein Schaltjahr");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide explanation as well, not just code.

Answer (score -2):

```
static int GeveDays()
{
    int days;
    if ((DateTime.Now).Year / 4 != 1 || (DateTime.Now).Year / 400 != 1) {
        Console.WriteLine("it is a common year");
        days = 365;
        return days;
    }
    else if ((DateTime.Now).Year / 100 != 1) {
        Console.WriteLine("it is a leap year");
        days = 366;
        return days;
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("it is a leap year");
        days = 366;
        return days;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
    int x= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if((x%400==0)||(x%100==0)||(x%4==0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" \n\n\n The year is a leap year ...!");
    }
    else
    {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n The year is not a leap year");
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.

Comment: your if is wrong. it should be `(x % 400 == 0 || x % 100 != 0 && x % 4 == 0)`