# How to obtain input from the user and provide feedback

Tags: c#, input, output, console-application

I am a newbie in coding - just starting my way up. The build is successful, but i wanted to add input- output to get a consumer response, to check if it in fact works. Thank you

```
using System;

namespace LeapYear
{
    public static class Leap
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a year ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static bool IsLeapYear(int year)
            { 

            if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 ==0)

            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736095/check-to-see-if-year-is-leap-year

Comment: FYI: Dotnet framework has a method already for `IsLeapYear` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.isleapyear?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a year ");

        //Console.ReadLine returns the entered data as a string
        var yearString = Console.ReadLine();

        //Convert the string to an int
        int year = Int32.Parse(yearString);

        //Now we can call your function, passing the year variable and recording the bool value passed back
        var isLeapYearAnswer = IsLeapYear(year);

        //Print the answer to the console
        Console.WriteLine(isLeapYearAnswer);
    }

    public static bool IsLeapYear(int year)
    { 
        if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 ==0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bDDudm)