# Find next occurrence of a date in C#

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I would like to parse a date, identified by month and day, into a valid `DateTime` occurring in the future.

Assume today is `2023-05-06`, below is a table of input and output values:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `06-24` | `2023-06-24` |
| `01-05` | `2024-01-05` |
| `02-29` | `2024-02-29` |

A naive way of achieving this would be to test if using `DateTime.Now.Year` for the `Year` portion produces a date in the future or not:

```
var today = DateTime.Now;
bool dateInFuture = new DateTime(today.Year, 02, 29)).CompareTo(today);
```

However you might have noticed that this will cause an exception as `2023-02-29` is not a valid date.

Ideally I would like this code to be able to work out if the date is actually invalid, so if `00-46` is passed as input it can tell me that that is not a real date, but that's a little tricky as my current implementation fails with dates that are actually valid.

Comment: "Ideally I would like this code to be able to work out if the date is actually invalid" - That is what Exceptions and exception handling is for. Use a `try/catch` around the code and then do something in the `catch` on failure.

Comment: The only date in a year that comes and goes is 29th of February so you can easily special case that one and handle everything else in the same manner.

Comment: I don't get why those latter two are 2024; is 2023 not future enough for them? is 29th feb 2023 not simply 01 march? Must you have at least a year between Now and the proposed date?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen I was hoping that there would be a way to achieve this without adding special cases as I would prefer not to write code to detect leap years if I can help it

Comment: @CaiusJard all of the dates are from the viewpoint of 2023-05-06, as the main issue I have found is with leap years. If it is currently 2023-05-06 and I need to do something on January 5th I can't travel back in time to 2023-01-05, so the next valid date would be 2024-01-05

Comment: Ah, yes.. I missed the 2023 part in *Assume today is 2023-05-06* :)

Comment: *I would prefer not to write code to detect leap years* - it's only `year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);` by the way

Comment: IMHO append a known leap year to the string, parse that, then add years.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - That wouldn't work for leap years. `(new DateTime(2024, 2, 29)).AddYears(1).AddYears(1).AddYears(1).AddYears(1)` is `2028-02-28`, but `(new DateTime(2024, 2, 29)).AddYears(4)` is `2028-02-29`.

Comment: Not one at a time. Add `n` years to get the current year, then if that is in the past, add `n+1` years from the source date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take:

```
DateTime? GetFutureDateFromMonthDay(DateTime today, string monthDay) =>
    Enumerable
        .Range(today.Year, 9)
        .Select(y => DateTime.TryParse($"{y}-{monthDay}", out DateTime result) ? (DateTime?)result : null)
        .Where(x => x != null)
        .Where(x => x > today)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that it looks ahead 9 years as it is possible to have an 8 year gap between leap years and you want to ensure that you are getting a future date, so it may require a further year. Changing `today` to `new DateTime(2096, 5, 6)` shows that issue.

So, given this input:

```
var today = new DateTime(2023, 5, 6);

var data = new[]
{
    new { input = "06-24", output = (DateTime?)new DateTime(2023, 6, 24) },
    new { input = "01-05", output = (DateTime?)new DateTime(2024, 1, 5) },
    new { input = "02-29", output = (DateTime?)new DateTime(2024, 2, 29) },
    new { input = "00-46", output = (DateTime?)null },
};
```

I run this query:

```
var query =
    from d in data
    let expected = d.output
    let actual = GetFutureDateFromMonthDay(today, d.input)
    select new
    {
        d.input,
        expected,
        actual,
        check = actual == expected,
    };
```

I get this result:

[image: result]

If go ahead and try `new DateTime(2096, 5, 6)` I now get this:

[image: 2096]

This code produces the future date or it returns `null` to indicate that the input was bad.

Comment: I actually really like this one, LINQ truly is a blessing to C# developers everywhere. Thanks again for your input

Comment: I just tested it out and it worked perfectly, you also get bonus points as it worked within an EntityFramework Select so I didn't need to do anything weird to get it working.

Answer (score -1):

This may help:

```
var input = "02-29";
var year = DateTime.Today.Year;
if (DateTime.TryParse($"{year}-{input}", out DateTime date))
{
    var isFutureDate = date > DateTime.Now;
}
else
{
    // TODO: Manage error
}
```

You can define a method to that:

```
public static bool TryGetDate(string input, out DateTime date)
{
    var year = DateTime.Today.Year;

    if (input == "02-29")
    {
        while (!DateTime.IsLeapYear(year))
        {
            year++;
        }
    }

    if (DateTime.TryParse($"{year}-{input}", out date))
    {
        if (date < DateTime.Now)
        {
            date = date.AddYears(1);
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And use it:

```
var input = "02-29";
if (TryGetDate(input, out DateTime date))
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // TODO: Manage error
}
```

Comment: This is kind of what I was thinking, but in 2023 (or any year just before a leap year) you'll end up in the else statement for 02-29, even though the date is technically valid, basically how can I make this function return 2024-02-09

Comment: You need manage that special case. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't realise that there was an IsLeapYear method until I saw Marco's answer

Comment: You can change the first `if` to a `while` and do away with the `do/while`

Comment: @CaiusJard it's more or less the same because the if is necessary and the number of IsLeapYear calls are the same. But it's true, one line less and IsLeapYear moved from if to while. It's changed, thanks for the appoinment.

Comment: Your code doesn't give the output that the OP is expecting.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for pointing. I missunderstand the question.

Comment: @Victor - It's still not producing the correct result. The first two examples aren't right. And if the `today` date were `new DateTime(2024, 5, 6)` then it's not right for all of them.

Comment: @Enigmativity After my last edit, it's right. Here https://dotnetfiddle.net/vOlmOR you can see a test with 2023-05-06 as today date and the output is that question expects to get.

Comment: @Victor - Your code in the answer is different from the fiddle. The answer still has `DateTime.Today` and `DateTime.Now` hard coded. Also, you leap year code doesn't work. If I use the fiddle code and start with `new DateTime(2024, 5, 6)` I get `2025-02-28` as the leap year date. And, if I start with `new DateTime(2096, 5, 6)` then your answer is `2097-02-28` and the correct answer is `2104-02-29`.

Comment: @Enigmativity The fiddle is the same as the code in my answer except for the fact that you can change the current date. I thought you were looking for a future date (DateTime.Now) and that's why in my answer I use DateTime.Now and in the Fiddle (to be able to test other dates) a variable. I didn't understand until now (I'm Spanish) that you want to keep the month and day of the date. I thought you were simply looking for a valid date in the future.

Comment: @Victor - The OP said "Assume today is 2023-05-06". It's part of the question that this date could change.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `DateTime.IsLeapYear(year)` - as is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39736134/12511801) in conjuction with [DateTime.TryParse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39736134/12511801) for check if the value to convert is a valid DateTime:

You can test this code in [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iMt9mF):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
Int32 year = DateTime.IsLeapYear(today.Year) ? today.Year : today.AddYears(-2).Year;
DateTime tempDate = DateTime.Now;

// String is concatenated in "yyyy-MM-dd" format: 
if (!DateTime.TryParse(year.ToString() + "-02-29", out tempDate))
{
    // Date is not valid.
    Console.WriteLine("Date (" + year.ToString() + "-02-29" + ") is not valid");
}
else
{
    // Date with "yyyy-MM-dd" format: 
    Console.WriteLine("Date is valid: " + tempDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
```

Comment: I didn't realise that method existed, I was trying to avoid writing (and testing) custom code to detect leap years, but I might be okay if there is already built in method that can do it for me

Comment: Oof, `DateTime.TryParse(year.ToString() + "/02/29"` - surely this can be done without all the stringing along?

Comment: @CaiusJard I really don't know, this was my first attempt, and yes, it must be another (*even better*) ways to do it :)

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes - Your code does not give the required output with the OP's input. You get the wrong year on the first two inputs and no result for the leap year date.